# Withdrawing from an already deployed smart contract

Tags: smart-contract-wallets

Please don't be too harsh on me.

I have followed the steps I found to create a smart contract, not knowing anything I'm doing - and I have successfully funded it.

Is there a way for me to recover the funds from this contract?
here's the code https://pastebin.com/HYrV2tei

I'm the owner.

thanks for any input.

Comment: Which network is the contract deployed in? And can u show the code the address is not enough if the contract is not verified

Comment: it's developed on Avalanche,  

here's the code https://pastebin.com/HYrV2tei

Comment: Sorry for your loss but the link is a scam contract. Using an ipfs link for code without any valid reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is a scam contract. All it does is send the funds you sent it to somebody else. After you sent funds to it, they can only be sent to the scammer. Sorry. This is why it is dangerous to execute code you don't understand.

Comment: but the AVAX I funded to this contract are still there.. I am the only one that has made transactions with it. Do you see the address that would receive the AVAX? I don't.

Comment: Yes, I see the address. This line `address(uint160(router.pangolinSwapAddress())).transfer(` will send the balance to the address in `router.pangolinSwapAddress()`. The router is initiated via the ipfs url in the contract. Go to that ipfs url and you'll see the address in pangolinSwapAddress. Your funds are locked in the contract - the only withdraw method will withdraw it to the scammer's address.

Comment: the ipfs https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmYAojmgsVWC4RJ7XEdPUxiD4jAMXrRjEiEUkU8XA2sgaf shows three different Avalanche address but none of them shows signs of fraudolent activity to me.. 

https://snowtrace.io/address/0xe02df9e3e622debdd69fb838bb799e3f168902c5 first 

https://snowtrace.io/address/0x05ff2b0db69458a0750badebc4f9e13add608c7f
 second
https://snowtrace.io/address/0x8373a10c4b547324cb18fb8fd8a1a1bfb09fe0d7
 third

Comment: How do you decide what is fraud activity and what is not? You can see that the pangolin swap address is not a contract. Also, swaps don't work by just transferring funds to them, usually some function is called. You can also see that the whole code is commented out and the function you'll call will end up doing nothing but send the funds to that address.

Comment: so you say that AVAX is lost, huh?

Comment: Yeah. [comment too short adding characters]